# Prove that a triangle exists using the triangle inequality.

Tags: inequality, triangles, triangle-inequality

I need help with the following question:

> It is given that there is a triangle with sides of lengths a, b and c units.
>
> Prove that there exists a triangle having sides of lengths
> $\sqrt{a(b+c-a)}, \sqrt{b(a+c-b)}$ and $\sqrt{c(a+b-c)}$ units.

Here's what I have so far:

$\sqrt{a(b+c-a)} + \sqrt{b(a+c-b)} \geq \sqrt{c(a+b-c)}$

$a(b+c-a) + 2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} + b(a+c-b) \geq {c(a+b-c)}$

$2ab - a^2 - b^2 + 2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \geq -c^2$

$2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} -(a-b)^2 \geq -c^2$

$-2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \leq c^2 -(a-b)^2$

$-2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \leq (b + c - a)(a + c - b)$

I thought to divide both sides by $\sqrt{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}$ but either $\sqrt{b+c-a}$ or $\sqrt{a+c-b}$ might be $0$. I am unable to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you for your advice! I will make the necessary improvements to the post.

Comment: Can you show your work for what you tried? EG Can you square both sides and manipulate what you got, bearing in mind that those $a+b-c$ terms are positive.

Comment: As mentioned by @AnotherUser above, it would be helpful if you could add some context. Why are you asking this question? What is the motivation behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b+c-a=x$, $a+c-b=y$ and $a+b-c=z$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{(y+z)x}+\sqrt{(x+z)y}>\sqrt{(x+y)z},$$ which is true because
$$\sqrt{(y+z)x}+\sqrt{(x+z)y}>\sqrt{(y+z)x+(x+z)y}>\sqrt{(x+y)z}.$$
By the same way we can prove another two inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

*Let us assume that there exists a triangle having sides of lengths $\sqrt{a(b+c-a)}, \sqrt{b(a+c-b)}$ and $\sqrt{c(a+b-c)}$ units.*

$\implies$ $\sqrt{a(b+c-a)} + \sqrt{b(a+c-b)} \geq \sqrt{c(a+b-c)}$

*Clearly both sides are positive, hence we may square both sides without disturbing the inquality,*

$\implies$ $a(b+c-a) + 2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} + b(a+c-b) \geq {c(a+b-c)}$

$2ab - a^2 - b^2 + 2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \geq -c^2$

$2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} -(a-b)^2 \geq -c^2$

$-2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \leq c^2 -(a-b)^2$

$-2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \leq (b + c - a)(a + c - b)$

Now, RHS is neccesarily positive and for the case of LHS we got $2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}$ positive too $\implies$ $-2\sqrt{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}$ is negative.

Since, $f(x)=x^2$ is decreasing in the interval $x\le0$, we must flip the inequality,

$\implies$ By squaring both sides again, we get,
$4{ab(b+c-a)(a+c-b)} \ge {[(b+c-a)(a+c-b)]}^2$

Dividing both sides by $(b+c-a)(a+c-b)$ , i.e. positive, we get,
$4ab \ge (b+c-a)(a+c-b) =c^2 -(a-b)^2$

$(a-b)^2+4ab \ge c^2$

$(a+b)^2 \ge c^2$

*Square-rooting both sides, we get,*
$ a+b \ge c$
which is true since it is given that there exists a triangle with sides of lengths a, b and c units.

*Therefore, our assumption is true and there exists a triangle having sides of lengths $\sqrt{a(b+c-a)}, \sqrt{b(a+c-b)}$ and $\sqrt{c(a+b-c)}$ units.*

Comment: Are you not worried about the logic? It seems you begin by assuming the statement that we are trying to prove. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: @311411 Well, I will keep that in mind now onwards. Any ways to fix it? I read about $\iff$ in a answer here, shall I use it instead of $\implies$ or try proving it the other way round? Anyways, I now feel I will be posting a question about this myself that why cant we assume in the starting of our proof..?? Confused. life :(